# GO C-Style Console Application

Tags: windows, go, cmd, go-cobra

I created a Go CLI app with the cobra framework via the `cobra add` command. After building it with `go build` it works totally fine if I'm in the repository in the windows cmd. If I click on the `.exe` I get the following message on a terminal:

```
This is a command line tool.

You need to open cmd.exe and run it from there.
```

This is not suitable for my case. I'd like to have a console applocation like in C or C++ which opens directly and you can type in commands there. Do you have any suggestions how I could realize this while using cobra?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is done on purpose as no arguments will be provided to the command when started through explorer.exe, as the main purpose of using cobra is for parsing arguments and stuff.

To disable this feature.

Add this line in your `init()`

```
func init(){
  cobra.MousetrapHelpText = ""
}
```

This let's your program run, and it exits immediately, to see if it's working fine.
Use `time.Sleep()`, so that you can see the output.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Right now I can see the first output. But I'd like to open a fully functional console so I don't have to navigate through my file system.

Comment: >But I'd like to open a fully functional console so I don't have to navigate through my file system. I don't understand what you were asking.

Comment: I want to have the application and the corresponding database in one folder. If I click on the `.exe` it will open a terminal where I can make my inputs. Just as in a C console application.

Comment: @alexfwulf Maybe you can consider using https://github.com/c-bata/go-prompt to implement what you require